# Inserting above the comment template

Tags: plugins, filters, hooks

I want to insert content, just above the comment template.I have tried all the word-press filters and hooks but failed.

I want to insert the content above the comment template, I mean above all comments.

Thanks

EDIT

```
function my_fields() {
 echo '<p>action/p>';

}
add_action('comment_notes_before','my_fields');
```

Please see the image-I want to insert content in color part of the image in single.php
[image]

Comment: show some code.

Comment: comment notes before action only works when user is not logged in try `comment_form_top`

Comment: *I want to insert the content above the comment template, I mean above all comments.* - what content: post content? Typical use of comment template is after post content. What's the matter here then? Please elaborate your question with more details and clarify the matter.

Comment: Added image please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mainly depends on a theme, whether there is a hook, in which you can call an action.

**Simple ways, how to do that:**

1. You insert your code directly into `single.php`,  right above the code calling `comments_template()`,
2. You create a hook (e.g. above comments_template()) as `do_action('my_hook')` and then you hook into it your function `add_action('my_hook', 'function_i_want_to_hook')`
3. Or you do the same as steps above, however, working with file, where comments template code resides, i.e. `comments.php`